# How can I disable quoting in the Python 2.4 CSV reader?

Tags: python, csv

I am writing a Python utility that needs to parse a large, regularly-updated CSV file I don't control.  The utility must run on a server with only Python 2.4 available.  The CSV file does not quote field values at all, but the [Python 2.4 version of the csv library](http://www.python.org/doc/2.4.3/lib/csv-fmt-params.html#csv-fmt-params) does not seem to give me any way to turn off quoting, it just allows me to set the quote character (`dialect.quotechar = '"'` or whatever).  If I try setting the quote character to `None` or the empty string, I get an error.

I can sort of work around this by setting `dialect.quotechar` to some "rare" character, but this is brittle, as there is no ASCII character I can absolutely guarantee will not show up in field values (except the delimiter, but if I set `dialect.quotechar = dialect.delimiter`, things go predictably haywire).

In [Python 2.5 and later](http://docs.python.org/library/csv.html), if I set `dialect.quoting` to `csv.QUOTE_NONE`, the CSV reader respects that and does not interpret any character as a quote character.  Is there any way to duplicate this behavior in Python 2.4?

**UPDATE**: Thanks Triptych and Mark Roddy for helping to narrow the problem down.  Here's a simplest-case demonstration:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import StringIO
>>> data = """
... 1,2,3,4,"5
... 1,2,3,4,5
... """
>>> reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data))
>>> for i in reader: print i
... 
[]
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "<stdin>", line 1, in ?
_csv.Error: newline inside string
```

The problem only occurs when there's a single double-quote character in the *final* column of a row.  Unfortunately, this situation exists in my dataset.  I've accepted Tanj's solution: manually assign a nonprinting character (`"\x07"` or `BEL`) as the quotechar.  This is hacky, but it works, and I haven't yet seen another solution that does.  Here's a demo of the solution in action:

```
>>> import csv
>>> import StringIO
>>> class MyDialect(csv.Dialect):
...     quotechar = '\x07'
...     delimiter = ','
...     lineterminator = '\n'
...     doublequote = False
...     skipinitialspace = False
...     quoting = csv.QUOTE_NONE
...     escapechar = '\\'
... 
>>> dialect = MyDialect()
>>> data = """
... 1,2,3,4,"5
... 1,2,3,4,5
... """
>>> reader = csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data), dialect=dialect)
>>> for i in reader: print i
... 
[]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '"5']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

In Python 2.5+ setting quoting to csv.QUOTE_NONE would be sufficient, and the value of `quotechar` would then be irrelevant.  (I'm actually getting my initial dialect via a `csv.Sniffer` and then overriding the quotechar value, not by subclassing `csv.Dialect`, but I don't want that to be a distraction from the real issue; the above two sessions demonstrate that `Sniffer` isn't the problem.)

Answer (score 13, accepted):

I don't know if python would like/allow it but could you use a non-printable ascii code such as BEL or BS (backspace) These I would think to be extremely rare.

Comment: Wow, good idea.  Setting csv.quotechar = '\x07' (BEL) seems to do the trick.  Can't imagine how they'd get that into their CSV data.

Comment: so, you could also set the quotechar to `''` (empty string). at least, this works on python 2.7 ... not sure about previous verisons so it may not have been applicable.

Comment: @underrun I mentioned in the question that setting `quotechar` to `None` or empty string fails (in Python 2.4).

Answer (score 3):

I tried a few examples using Python 2.4.3, and it seemed to be smart enough to detect that the fields were unquoted.

I know you've already accepted a (slightly hacky) answer, but have you tried just leaving the `reader.dialect.quotechar` value alone?  What happens if you do?

Any chance we could get example input?

Comment: I'm still interested in a less hacky approach, if there is one.  I can get some sample input uploaded soon.  The dialect I'm using is generated by a csv.Sniffer object (I need to be as robust as possible against format changes).  If I leave quotechar alone it seems to default to double-quote '"'.

Answer (score 0):

+1 for Triptych

Confirmation that csv.reader automatically handles csv files with out quotes:

```
>>> import StringIO
>>> import csv
>>> data="""
... 1,2,3,4,5
... 1,2,3,4,5
... 1,2,3,4,5
... """
>>> reader=csv.reader(StringIO.StringIO(data))
>>> for i in reader:
...     print i
... 
[]
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
['1', '2', '3', '4', '5']
```

Comment: This isn't really a relevant test, as no matter what quotechar is set to, quoting is optional; it can handle unquoted fields just fine.  The problem is when the quotechar appears in the data; and apparently, only when it appears in the final column.  Thanks for pushing me to narrow it down.