# Pandas - Is it possible to read_csv with no quotechar?

Tags: python, pandas, quotes

I am trying to read a csv file that has single instances of `"` in certain lines, ex:

```
car,"plane,jet
jet,ski,"hat
```

When I use pandas `read_csv` to read this file, it recognizes `"` as a quote character and does not correctly read in lines such as the one above. I would like to not have any quote character at all when I use `read_csv`.

I tried setting `quotechar=None` and `quotechar=''` but both spits out an error since `quotechar` has to be a string of length 1. Is it possible to not have a quotechar at all when using `read_csv`?

Thanks!

Comment: Seems like a duplicate of [Disable Quoting in CSV Reader](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/494054/how-can-i-disable-quoting-in-the-python-2-4-csv-reader)

Comment: Thanks for that link. However, that question seems to be talking about the csv library. I was talking specifically about the pandas library.

Comment: Along the same lines however, you should be able to set `quotechar='\x07'`. Which will almost certainly never exist in your actual file.

Comment: Thanks for that suggestion. I will do that but I still have a lingering feeling in the back of my head that something can go wrong XD. I hope pandas in the future can allow quotechar to be None or '' (blank string)

Comment: I'm not familiar with Pandas but it seems like from this [documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html) you can set `quoting=3` to accomplish this as well.

Comment: That did it mate! I would accept your answer if it weren't a comment, thx!

Answer (score 42, accepted):

From the [Pandas Documentation](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/generated/pandas.io.parsers.read_csv.html)

> quoting : int or csv.QUOTE_* instance, default None
>   Control field quoting behavior per csv.QUOTE_* constants. Use one of QUOTE_MINIMAL (0), QUOTE_ALL (1), QUOTE_NONNUMERIC (2) or QUOTE_NONE (3). Default (None) results in QUOTE_MINIMAL behavior.

So you'll want to include 
`quoting=3` as a parameter to your `read_csv()`.

Answer (score 28):

Jkdc's answer is correct, but I find it more readable to actually use the csv.QUOTE* instance as mentioned in the documentation. It wasn't clear to me which csv it meant at first, so I didn't know how to import that. Here's a code sample:

```
import pandas as pd
import csv

df1 = pd.read_csv('input_file.csv', quoting=csv.QUOTE_NONE)
```